# Error in transporting an application from development worklight to Worklight Server Consumer Edition

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight environment. I have created a small application "SampleHybridProject" using Worklight Developer studio and tested it successfully.

Now when I am trying to deploy it on the Worklight Server Consumer Edition, and hitting the following URL: `http://mymachine.com:9080/SampleHybridProject/console`

I am getting this error in my browser:

> Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /SampleHybridProject/console

I am using Worklight Edition 5.0.6. The Worklight Server is default "WAS with Liberty profile".

Here are the properties that I changed in worklight.properties file.

```
publicWorkLightHostname=localhost
publicWorkLightProtocol=http
publicWorkLightPort=9080
publicWorkLightContext=/SampleHybridProject

wl.db.type=MYSQL
wl.db.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqlinstalledonmypc:3306/WRKLGHT
wl.db.username=root
wl.db.password=admin
```

Here are the changes that I made in application-descriptor.xml:

```
<worklightServerRootURL>http://${local.IPAddress}:9080/SampleHybridProject</worklightServerRootURL>
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong or what I need to do?

Comment: Have you deployed the .war file to the Liberty application server?

Comment: Yes, I have placed the .war file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Worklight\server\wlp\templates\servers\defaultServer\apps" folder. 

Added following changes to server.xml file

<application id="SampleHybridProject" name="SampleHybridProject" location="SampleHybridProject.war" type="war">
        <classloader delegation="parentLast">
            <commonLibrary>
                <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar">
            </commonLibrary>
        </classloader>
</application>

And restarted the server.

Comment: I was placing the .war file at wrong location. Now I have placed it in "C:\ProgramData\IBM\Worklight\WAS85liberty-server\wlp\usr\servers\worklightServe‌​r\apps" and added the following entry to the "server.xml" file. <application id="SampleHybridProject" name="SampleHybridProject" location="SampleHybridProject.war" type="war"> <classloader delegation="parentLast"> <commonLibrary> <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar" /> </commonLibrary> </classloader> </application>

Comment: But now while accessing the console at "myhostserver:9080/SampleHybridProject/console";, I am getting the following error "Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter():81' Worklight Project not initialized at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.‌​java:81) ". Any idea about this error.

Comment: I have noted down following error in console.log file whenever I try to open the console for my custom application: {Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/IBM/Worklight/WAS85liberty-server/wlp/usr/shared/resources/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/UnifiedClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/sql/DataSource"}

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem and solved it. The problem is I was having this error in console.log file:

> Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/IBM/Worklight/WAS85liberty-server/wlp/usr/shared/resou‌​rces/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/UnifiedClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/sql/DataSource"

This was because I had a jar in the server/lib folder of my project which was causing this problem. I removed the jar from server/lib folder and redeployed the .war file. Now the console is getting loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any deployment errors in your liberty logs? A 404 on the context root generally means either the WAR was not found, or the context root defaults to something other than 'SampleHybridProject'. If the WAR appears to be loading correctly, it will output where it is listening on similar to:

> [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://[hostname]:port/SampleHybridProject/*

If it says the context root is anything other than SampleHybridProject, you can set it in the  tag in liberty's server.xml:

```
<application id="SampleHybridProject" name="SampleHybridProject" 
    location="SampleHybridProject.war" type="war"
    context-root="SampleHybridProject"> 
    ... 
</application>
```

Comment: I was placing the .war file at wrong location. Now I have placed it in "C:\ProgramData\IBM\Worklight\WAS85liberty-server\wlp\usr\servers\worklightServer\apps" and added the following entry to the "server.xml" file. <application id="SampleHybridProject" name="SampleHybridProject" location="SampleHybridProject.war" type="war"> 
  <classloader delegation="parentLast"> 
   <commonLibrary> 
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar" /> 
   </commonLibrary> 
  </classloader> 
 </application>

Comment: But now while accessing the console at "http://myhostserver:9080/SampleHybridProject/console", I am getting the following error "Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter():81'
  Worklight Project not initialized
   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:81) ". Any idea about this error.

Comment: I have noted down following error in console.log file whenever I try to open the console for my custom application: {Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/ProgramData/IBM/Worklight/WAS85liberty-server/wlp/usr/shared/resources/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/UnifiedClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/sql/DataSource"}